# How to reset 'plt.style.use('dark_background')'?

Tags: python

```
plt.style.use('dark_background')
```

I put this into my jupyter notebook and now all of my graphs have a black background. How do I change it back to the default of white background? If I remove the code from the jupyter notebook the graphs still all have a black background.

Comment: Conveniently, try: plt.style.use('default')

Comment: omg thank you!!!!!!!! :)

Answer (score 5):

There actually is a `default`. But it's not listed under
`plt.style.available`. Simply run:

```py
plt.style.use('default')
```

It returns the style to the default Matplotlib settings in your environment